# Change axios name in vue3, child components say its not defined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I want to better understand the concepts of vue3 and get acquainted with them. Please guide me. When I write `*app.config.globalProperties.axios = axios;*` in `app.js`, `axios` can be accessed inside the child components and can use `*axios.get("/").then....*`. This works correctly, but when this is changed to `*app.config.globalProperties.apicaller = axios;*` in the child component, `*apicaller .get("/").then....*` says `apicaller` is not defined.
Why? What's the point?

```js
//app.js
require("./bootstrap.js");
// import "./bazar-script";

import { createApp } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";

import ParRecipesGroup from "./vue/Components/Parts/RecipesGroup.vue";

const app = createApp({
    el: "#app",
    components: {
        "par-recipes-group": ParRecipesGroup,
    },
app.mount("#app");
app.config.globalProperties.apicaller = axios;
```

```js
app.js:19374 Uncaught ReferenceError: apicaller is not defined
    at Proxy.created (app.js:19374)
    at callWithErrorHandling (app.js:13914)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (app.js:13923)
    at callHook (app.js:9516)
    at applyOptions (app.js:9418)
    at finishComponentSetup (app.js:13651)
    at setupStatefulComponent (app.js:13570)
    at setupComponent (app.js:13500)
    at mountComponent (app.js:11361)
    at processComponent (app.js:11336)
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64oaI.jpg]

Comment: How do you call it inside the child component?

Comment: if use app.config.globalProperties.axios= axios; in app.js i use axios.get("/").then.... in child component and if use app.config.globalProperties.apicaller= axios; in app.js i use apicaller.get("/").then.... in child component